# Маршрутизация AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, маршрутизация, route, angular-routing

Есть приложение:

```
var betdeskApp = angular.module('betdeskApp', ["ngRoute"])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/registration',
    {
        templateUrl: 'registration.html',
        controller: 'regController'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/authorization',
    {
        templateUrl: 'authorization.html',
        controller: 'authController'
    });
});
```

есть страничка:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head lang="en" ng-app="betdeskApp">
    <title>BetDesk</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../script/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="../controllers/Initialize.js"></script>
    <script src="../controllers/authController.js"></script>
    <script src="../controllers/regController.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BetDesk</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#/registration"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/authorization"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <content class="row">
        <ng-view></ng-view>

    </content>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Логика такова, что при клике по ссылкам `Sing UP` и `Login` должны рендирится соответствующие представления, но этого не происходит. 
Подскажите что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: а что происходит? Судя по предоставленному коду - все должно работать

Comment: В том то и дело что ничего, и в консоли ошибок нет.

Comment: сделай [mcve] на [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) - чтобы можно было запустить и посмотреть что именно не работает. Сейчас ничего нельзя сказать

Comment: @Grundy единственное что меня смущает это место где подключается   директива `ng-app`, я обычно подключаю на `body`. и не может ли быть ошибок `jQuery` vs `Angular`

Comment: @Bald, и тут ты прав. Элемент помеченный атрибутом `ng-app` - является корневым для приложения. и все остальные директивы ищутся _внутри_ этого элемента. В данном случае - это элемент head, и внутри него почти ничего нет :-)

Comment: @РоманТимохов, для решения перенеси ng-app на html, либо на body, либо на content

Comment: Перенес - не помогло

Comment: @Grundy - закинул файлы на Plunker -  http://plnkr.co/edit/0XKmrKDrb3wFDunbY6fn?p=preview

Comment: @РоманТимохов, какая версия ангуляра?

Comment: @Grundy version 1.5.6

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52483/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в том, что я не правильно разместил директиву `ng-app`, разместив ее в теге `<head>`. Перенос директивы `ng-app` в тег `body` решил данную проблему. Была еще небольшая ошибка в коде - но это скорее всего механика.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/138078)

Comment: @Harry, почему не является?

Comment: @Grundy Если это ответ, то он должен, как мне кажется, быть более полным. Как вы понимаете, при выборе варианта текст идет стандартный - "Не является ответом на вопрос... и далее по тексту". Я бы сказал, что ответ слишком краткий, и нужно копаться в комментариях, чтобы точно понять, что и как. Увы, выбор при проверке предлагается небогатый. Словом, я считаю, что правильно было бы дать более полный ответ - с тем, как, куда перенести директиву etc etc. Выбрал ближайшую - по моему разумению - опцию при проверке.

Comment: @Harry в комментариях копаться нет нужды. ответ сводится к тому что необходимо правильно *подключить* директиву. хотя возможно ответ может быть закрыт как не воспроизводится, но я не уверен до конца в правильности такого решения

Comment: @Grundy я исправил ответ, написав более развернуто.

Comment: @Grundy Хорошо, в следующий раз я постараюсь не лениться и писать комментарии о необходимости развернуть ответ...